# Jest mock a function within object

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Trying the following :

```js
// Function Spies
const onSubmitSpy = jest.fn().mockName('onSubmitSpy');
const onHistoryPushSpy = jest.fn().mockName('onPushSpy');

// Default Props
const defaultProps = {
    signupUserMutation: onSubmitSpy,
    history: {
        push: onHistoryPushSpy
    }
};
```

Then within my test this spy gets called withing my code like this

```js
history.push('/');
```

(I verified with mock Response) but the call count in test response always remains 0.

I have a feeling this is maybe because this is a nested object I am missing something ?

```js
        test('should submit and call routing change', () => {
...
            expect(onHistoryPushSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        });
```

And I always get this error
Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called zero times.

Comment: how do you use defaultProps?

Comment: spread them like this        mountedWrapper = mount(
            <Registration {...defaultProps} } />
        );

Comment: so you run `history.push` inside your component that you pass there as a prop in the app, right? no `import history from './my_history'`?